# What does "writing" mean in "a note is a short piece of writing to help you remember something"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I don't understand what "writing" in "[a note is a short piece of writing to help you remember something](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/note_1?q=note)" mean?

In the dictionary, "**writing**" means "[words that have been written or painted on something.

There was writing all over the desk.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/writing?q=writing)"

**Is it some words? or is it a piece of paper?**

Does "**write a note/ make a note**" mean "**creating words reminding you to do something**"?

Comment: 'A short piece of writing' = 'something written down in a few words'.

Comment: A note may be to remind others, not yourself. piece of writing is not a piece of paper. And something can be written all over someone's face. But that's an idiom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *note,* like a *letter,* can mean either the written text or the piece of paper on which it is written. As the second definition in your dictionary says, it can mean a short letter.

A note can also be a few words that you write down to remind yourself to do something (TAKE CASSEROLE OUT OF FREEZER), to remember some information, or to give someone else some information (GONE TO SUPERMARKET. BACK IN 20 MINUTES.)

Answer (score 3):

"Writing" is noun derived from the particple form of "write".  It has the same relationship to "write" as "building" does to "build".

However "writing" is normally treated as non-count.  So one says "a piece of writing" to mean "a thing that is written".  A piece of writing could be anything from grafitti to a short memo, to an essay, to the manuscript of a book.

This is "a short piece of writing", and it is the definition of "note".  The "piece of writing" is the written thing, the words on the paper.  When you write a note, it is often a way of helping you *or someone else* be aware, or remember, something.